# Preloading background images

Tags: javascript, css, sass

I'm building a page that loops through 3 different backgrounds, changing every 750ms. To do this, I'm adding a class to the body with the relevent background image, changing with JS. For the first loop through, they flash because the image has to load, so it's not there instantly. Therefore is there any methods I can use to preload the images?

CSS:

```
&.backgrounds{
    background-position: center bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 130%;

    &.freddy{
        background-image: url(/img/illustrations/snapchat/snapchat_holding_page_freddy.jpg);
    }

    &.irene{
        background-image: url(/img/illustrations/snapchat/snapchat_holding_page_irene.jpg);
    }

    &.joe{
        background-image: url(/img/illustrations/snapchat/snapchat_holding_page_joe.jpg);
    }
}
```

JS:

```
setInterval(function() {
    if ( $('.backgrounds').hasClass('freddy') ){
        $('.backgrounds').removeClass('freddy').addClass('irene');

    } else if ( $('.backgrounds').hasClass('irene') ){
        $('.backgrounds').removeClass('irene').addClass('joe');

    } else if ( $('.backgrounds').hasClass('joe') ){
        $('.backgrounds').removeClass('joe').addClass('freddy');

    }
}, 750);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do something like this. `loadImages` returns a Promise that will resolve once all of the images are loaded. The `.then` attached to it calls `cycleImages`, which starts up the interval. Since you will need the URLs in the JS anyway to do the pre-loading, instead of class switching I'm directly manipulating the `background-image`, that way you can remove the image URLs from the CSS and save a few redundant bytes. This also makes it easier to expand the list of images in the future too, you only need to add an item to the array of images instead of maintaining a complicated if statement.

```js
function loadImages (images) {
  // each image will be loaded by this function.
  // it returns a Promise that will resolve once
  // the image has finished loading
  let loader = function (src) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      let img = new Image();
      img.onload = function () {
        // resolve the promise with our url so it is
        // returned in the result of Promise.all
        resolve(src);
      };
      img.onerror = function (err) {
        reject(err);
      };
      img.src = src;
    });
  };

  // create an image loader for each url
  let loaders = [];
  images.forEach(function (image) {
    loaders.push(loader(image));
  });

  // Promise.all will return a promise that will resolve once all of of our
  // image loader promises resolve
  return Promise.all(loaders);
}


// the images we are going to display
let myImages = [
  'http://www.gifpng.com/400x200',
  'http://www.gifpng.com/400x200/ffffff/000000',
  'http://www.gifpng.com/400x200/000000/ffffff'
];

// $(document).ready(fn) is deprecated,
// use the $(fn) form instead
$(function() {

  // after the images are loaded this will be called with an array of the loaded images
  function cycleImages (images) {
    let index = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
      // since we need an array of the image names to preload them anyway,
      // just load them via JS instead of class switching so you can cut them
      // out of the CSS and save some space by not being redundant
      $('#backgrounds').css('backgroundImage', 'url("' + images[index] + '")');
      // increment, roll over to 0 if at length after increment
      index = (index + 1) % images.length;
    }, 750);
  }


  // load the images and start cycling through them after they are loaded
  loadImages(myImages).then(cycleImages).catch(function (err) {
    console.error(err);
  });
});
```

```css
#backgrounds {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="backgrounds"></div>
```

**Edit:**
Taking [Just a student](https://stackoverflow.com/users/962603/just-a-student)'s comments into account, here is a version that will only switch the image once it is loaded, but do it right away if it is loaded. It also skips images that failed to load. Since `cycleImages` is no longer called via `.then`, I also changed it so it accepts a target element (as a jQuery object) along with an array of images promises. That way you can easily use this on multiple places on a page with different images sets if you wanted to.

```js
function loadImages (images) {
  // each image will be loaded by this function.
  // it returns a Promise that will resolve once
  // the image has finished loading
  let loader = function (src) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      let img = new Image();
      img.onload = function () {
        // resolve the promise with our url
        resolve(src);
      };
      img.onerror = function (err) {
        reject(err);
      };
      img.src = src;
    });
  };

  // return an array of image-loading promises
  return images.map(function (image) {
    return loader(image);
  });
}


// the images we are going to display
let myImages = [
  'http://www.gifpng.com/400x200',
  'http://www.invalid-domain-name.foo/this-url-certainly-does-not-exist.jpg',
  'http://www.gifpng.com/400x200/ffffff/000000',
  'http://www.gifpng.com/400x200/000000/ffffff'
];

// $(document).ready(fn) is deprecated,
// use the $(fn) form instead
$(function() {

  // this receives an array of the promises for each image
  function cycleImages ($target, images) {
    let index = 0,
      interval = 750; // how many ms to wait before attempting to switch images

    function nextImage () {
      // p is the promise for the current image
      let p = images[index],
        next = function (wait) {
          // increment our counter and wait to display the next one
          index = (index + 1) % images.length;
          setTimeout(nextImage, wait);
        };

      // wait for this image to load or fail to load
      p.then(function (src) {
        // it loaded, display it
        $target.css('backgroundImage', 'url("' + src + '")');
        next(interval);
      }).catch(function (err) {
        // this one failed to load, skip it
        next(0);
      });

    }

    // start cycling
    nextImage();
  }


  // load the images and start cycling through them as they are loaded
  cycleImages($('#backgrounds'), loadImages(myImages));
});
```

```css
#backgrounds {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="backgrounds"></div>
```

Instead of hard-coding the interval between images changes you could also pass that in as a parameter. At that point though, I would refactor it to use a config object to pass everything but the image promise array: `cycleImages(myImages, {target: $('#backgrounds'), interval: 1000});`

Comment: One side note, you might want to think about changing the interval to every few seconds instead of every 750ms. Most people will get really annoyed at something that is flashing by that fast. As someone with attention deficit disorder, I can tell you that something flashing that fast on a page makes it really hard to concentrate on reading anything on the page; it's just too distracting. Even people without ADD might be impaired by the distraction.

Comment: Great answer! One suggestion: currently, all images are loaded before the first one is shown. It could be a nice alternative solution to only load an image when it is needed and simply delay the switch until the Promise has resolved. This would mean that for the first loop, you cannot yet use an interval, but instead need to ensure that both (a) 750ms (or whatever you set) have passed and (b) the next image is loaded. That can in fact nicely be done with Promises as well.

Comment: Oh, and another disadvantage of the current solution is that no background image will be shown even if only one cannot be accessed.

Comment: @Justastudent I've added an alternate solution based on your suggestions. Thanks for your input, it helped me think about how it could be improved. I like what it caused me to come up with :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can load them in javascript. Like:

```
(new Image()).src = url1;
(new Image()).src = url2;
(new Image()).src = url3;
```

Change the "url1", "url2", "url3" with you own image urls. Browser will load the image but they wont be visible anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting idea.

Could you potentially load them in the background so like:

```
<div class="hidden-images">
    <img src="img1.jpg" />
    <img src="img2.jpg" />
    <img src="img3.jpg" />
</div>
```

Then in CSS

```
.hidden-images {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
 }
```

Then on whatever you sort of main container div is, slap the following on it?

```
 .main-container {
     position: relative;
     z-index: 2; // Or higher, whatever is needed
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do also do this with different html and css structure like this.

html

```
<div class="backgrounds">
  <div class="background freddy"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.backgrounds{
    background-color: transparent;
    background-position: center bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 130%;
    height: 250px;
    width; 100%;
}

.backgrounds .freddy{
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background-image: url('http://adrianweb.net/includes/images/hero.jpg');
    }

.backgrounds .irene{
         height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background-image: url('http://adrianweb.net/includes/images/projects-blur.png');
    }

.backgrounds .joe{
         height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background-image: url('http://adrianweb.net/includes/images/contacts-blur.png');
    }
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function() {
    if ( $('.background').hasClass('freddy') ){
        $('.background').removeClass('freddy').addClass('irene');

    } else if ( $('.background').hasClass('irene') ){
        $('.background').removeClass('irene').addClass('joe');

    } else if ( $('.background').hasClass('joe') ){
        $('.background').removeClass('joe').addClass('freddy');

    }
}, 750);
});
```

Maybe you can add transition/animation to make it look fade in and out.

Sample codepen below:

http://codepen.io/adrianrios/pen/yMEpEv