# SVGs not rendered in Firefox 60 sometimes

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, svg

This is a problem I've been researching for a few hours now and I still don't have even the slightest idea what causes this behaviour. I'd appreciate even the smallest ideas or pointers.

Our application has some dynamic icons. The icons are SVGs. They are displayed by adding a div with a set width and height and creating a style tag in the head containing the icon's URL as the background of the div's ::before-attribute. Here is a working example that's much clearer than my description ([also avialable as a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cpL8e1h4/36/)).

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <!-- These are generated dynamically -->
  <div class="icon" data-icon="my_awesome_icon"></div>
  <div class="icon" data-icon="my_other_awesome_icon"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  width: 300px;
}

.icon {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.icon::before {
  position:absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 20px;
  content: '';
}
```

**JS**

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.type = 'text/css';

//This is created dynamically, paths are relative
var css = '[data-icon="my_awesome_icon"]::before { background:url("relative/path/to/my_icon.svg"); }';
style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));

css = '[data-icon="my_other_awesome_icon"]::before { background:url("relative/path/to/my_other_icon.svg"); }';
style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));

head.appendChild(style);
```

This is working fine most of the time. Now for one of our clients running the latest Firefox ESR release 60.1.0 without addons on Windows 7 icons are not shown sporadically. About once every 500 refreshs one or several of the icons fail to render. The divs are there, the CSS is there, the rule applies to the div. A request to load the SVG from the server is sent and responds with status code 200. The SVGs are the same shown 499 times before and are valid. A few times when hitting refresh the icons briefly showed up before the page reloaded. I couldn't reproduce the problem when using PNGs instead of SVGs.

I suspected this to be a race condition between adding the div and the style tag but some testing confirmed that it works no matter what happens first.

To make this even worse I could not reproduce the problem on my or my colleagues machines but on multiple machines at the client. As I said I'm at a total loss here and every idea what the culprit could be will help.

Comment: intermittent problems on one clients machines - sounds like a client issue :p

Comment: you probably have to preload your background images  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42998327/preloading-background-images

Comment: The images aren't slow to load but do not show up at all even after Firefox network analysis shows the image as loaded. Is there anything I'm missing how preloading would help with this problem?

Comment: Firefox is really problematic with SVG, may be you can embed the image instead of the link, check the link.
https://css-tricks.com/lodge/svg/09-svg-data-uris/

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll test this to see if it fixes the problem but I fear that won't be feasible for our application in the long run.